# MS SQL Store procedure insert not work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried creating a store procedure for MS SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YEARENDPROCESSING
AS
DECLARE @VAR AS VARCHAR(9)    

DECLARE ACURSOR CURSOR FOR 
SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLEA

OPEN ACURSOR 
 FETCH NEXT FROM ACURSOR INTO  @VAR
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLEB SELECT * FROM TABLEC WHERE TABLEC.COLUMNC = @VAR
FETCH NEXT FROM ACURSOR INTO @VAR
    END
    CLOSE ACURSOR 
    DEALLOCATE ACURSOR
```

Assuming TableC column and TableB have identical columns
I get the result saying X rows affected
But in actual table I see nothing.

I have a new Finding

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YEARENDPROCESSING
AS
DECLARE @VAR AS VARCHAR(9)    

DECLARE ACURSOR CURSOR FOR 
SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLEA

OPEN ACURSOR 
 FETCH NEXT FROM ACURSOR INTO  @VAR
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLEB SELECT * FROM TABLEC WHERE TABLEC.COLUMNC = @VAR
    DELETE TABLEF where columnf = @VAR
FETCH NEXT FROM ACURSOR INTO @VAR
    END
    CLOSE ACURSOR 
    DEALLOCATE ACURSOR
```

Will get x row affected for the insert and x row affected for the delete

But the actual fact is insert result cannot be seen in the physical table itself. I can see the result of I remove the Delete query. Anyone knows why?

Comment: How are you connecting to the table to verify it is empty? Are you sure you're in the right database? Are you sure you're looking at `dbo.TABLEB` and not `some_other_schema.TABLEB`? Why isn't your code [using the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx)? Is your connection string anything like `AttachDbFileName`?

Comment: When I replace "INSERT INTO TABLEB SELECT * FROM TABLEC WHERE TABLEB.COLUMNC = @var" with  "Insert into TABLEB (COLUMND)VALUE('TEST')" works So is the right database

Comment: Why does the insert have a where clause referencing `TableB`? Shouldn't it be `WHERE TABLEA.COLUMNC = @VAR` or something like that? Why is this a cursor anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Your code shouldn't have a cursor. You can do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YearEndProcessing
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.TableB(column1, column2, ...)
    SELECT column1, column2, ...
    FROM dbo.TableA;
END
GO
```

Well, you changed the code, now there's a third table involved, so let me try again without a cursor:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YearEndProcessing
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.TableB(column1, column2, ...)
    SELECT c.column1, c.column2, ...
    FROM dbo.TableA AS a
    INNER JOIN dbo.TableC AS c
    ON a.[Column] = c.[ColumnC];
END
GO
```

Or:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YearEndProcessing
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.TableB(column1, column2, ...)
    SELECT c.column1, c.column2, ...
    FROM dbo.TableC AS c
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableA AS a
      WHERE a.[Column] = c.[ColumnC]
    );
END
GO
```

You shouldn't use the `INSERT TABLE SELECT * FROM TABLE` pattern - this is very prone to breaking in the future ([see this post for more details](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)). Also see [this post about using a schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) and these posts about cursor usage - it should be reserved for cases that actually need it, and when you do actually need it, don't use the default options:

https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options

As for why you see rows inserted but then later can't see the data, I suspect you're looking at a table in the wrong database, in the wrong schema, or you have multiple copies of your database (which happens when you use `User Instance` and `AttachDbFileName` options in your connection string).

Comment: No is not the wrong table I am sure. There is only one TABLEB

Comment: I have actually many other update and delete to other table taking the @var as reference. is it possible to achieve without cursor as well?

Comment: @user1761160 Almost certainly, but I can't re-write your code for you if I can't see it. Please don't change this question a dozen times - solve the problem of finding your data in the right place, *then* create a *different* question asking how to change your entire code sample (not just a fragment and a vague description of the rest) to not use a cursor.

Comment: Ya aaron sorry about that. I posted my new findings which is new to me.